# remove rows from data frame whose column values don't match another data frame's column values - R

Tags: r

So I have two data frames of different dimensions.

The first one, x, is about 10,000 rows and long looks like:

```
Year    ID    Number
2008.1  38573 1
2008.2  24395 3
```

(a lot of data in between)

```
2008.4  532   4
```

The second one, x2, is about 80,000 rows long and looks like:

```
Year    ID     Number
2008.1  38573  2
2008.2  24395  3
```

(a lot of data in between)

```
2008.4  532    4
```

Basically, I want to remove the rows in the second data that satisfy the following condition: that the Year, ID and Number values in the row don't match any rows of the first data frame. So in the above example, I'd remove row 1 from the second data frame, because the Number doesn't match.

I've tried:

```
x2new <- x2[(x2$ID == x$ID && x2$Year==x$Year && x2$Number == x$Number),]
```

But it doesn't work because the lengths of the two data frames are different.

I've tried doing a double for loop to remove rows that don't have all 3 conditions, but R simply can't do that many iterations.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: can you provide a simple reproducible example

Comment: the reason your line of code does not work is because you are using `&&` instead of `&`.   Please have a look at `?'&'` in `R`.   That being said, you most likely want to avoid a series of such searches when you have 10k * 80k pairs of rows.  `merge` as @agstudy suggested is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `merge`

```
 merge(dat1,dat2)
```

Using your data for example:

```
dat1 <- read.table(text='Year,ID,Number
2008.1,38573,1
2008.4,532,4
2008.2,24395,3',header=TRUE,sep=',')

dat2 <- read.table(text='Year,ID,Number
2008.1,38573,2
2008.4,532,4
2008.2,24395,3',header=TRUE,sep=',')
```

Then you get :

```
merge(dat1,dat2)
    Year    ID Number
1 2008.2 24395      3
2 2008.4   532      4
```

Comment: I posted a simplified version of my datasets. The first one has about 500 columns, second one has about 70 columns, so the dimensions are different. I wouldn't be able to do text='' because it'd be too much to paste in. Is there a way where I could remove particular rows of the second data set if the column values of certain columns don't match those of another data set?

Comment: @user2303557 here, the `text=...` is just to read your data, since you don't give a reproducible example. It is just an artifact to create your data. Forget about it. For your your remark about columns numbers, the merge by default will be done in the intersection of colnames of the 2 data.frames.

Comment: I just included 3 columns even thouugh the data frames have 60 and 500 something columns. Is there a way I can specify the merge function to check for matches on 3 particular columns?

Comment: @user2303557 yes. you can specify `by.x` and `by.y` argument like this : `merge(dat1,dat2,by.x=c('Year','ID','Number'),
      by.y=c('Year','ID','Number'))` . Next time try to give a reproducible example. The more you specify your question , the better you get a precise answer. see `?merge` for more details.

Comment: Also may be easier to strip non-essential columns from the first data frame before merging: `merge(dat1[,c('Year','ID','Number')],dat2,by.x=c('Year','ID','Number'), by.y=c('Year','ID','Number'))`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH to agstudy and Blue Magister! this worked, as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to remove all the rows where no one of three columns has a match in the first data frame, and keep all the row where at least one column has a match, right? if so, just do this:

```
newX2 <- x2[ x2$ID %in% x$ID | x2$Year %in% x$Year | x2$Number %in% x$Number,]
```

Comment: I meant that I only want to keep the row if there's a match on all three, sorry if that was unclear. The problem I have with %in% (based on my knowledge of it) is that I want the Id, Year, and Number of row x of data frame 2 to all match the ID, Year and Number of data frame 1. Right now, I think it's just checking if the ID, Year and Number of data frame 2 exist in data frame 1.

Comment: @user2303557 Ok sorry, my fault. Here it's 5:45 AM ... :) then just change  or, |, with and, &.